# sampling of data based on a column

Tags: sql

We are trying to create a sample of from a heavy volume for testing purpose.
 The data to be specific looks like this

```
CustomerId   Customer_name  PurchaseId Purchase date  
1234         Robert Benson  ABC123      12/07/2012
1218         Gary Thomas    PP122           26/01/2013
1254         Robert Sharma  PML563      27/04/2012
1218         Gary Thomas    PR124       06/03/2013
1234         Benson Cruiso  LML123      14/07/2012
1234         Martha Cruiso  FMPL123     15/07/2012
```

I want the result data as:

```
GroupID  CustomerId   Customer_name  PurchaseId Purchase date  
1   1218         Gary Thomas    PR124       06/03/2013
1   1218         Gary Thomas    PP122           26/01/2013
2   1234         Robert Benson  ABC123      12/07/2012
2   1234         Benson Cruiso  LML123      14/07/2012
2   1234         Martha Cruiso  FMPL123     15/07/2012
3   1254         Robert Sharma  PML563      27/04/2012
```

basically I want to have an additional one more column which will identify the rows to one set based on one column ie CustomerId here.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

This is the position of the current customer ID in the sorted list of unique customer IDs. To get the position in the sorted list, count how many smaller values there are:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
              FROM MyTable) AS UniqueIDs
        WHERE UniqueIDs.CustomerID <= MyTable.CustomerID
       ) AS GroupID,
       *
FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: Even though the data in is unsorted on CustomerId will it be able to sort it same time provide the sorted position. Or before execute the query the data should be sorted on CustomerId column

Comment: When counting rows, the order of those rows does not matter.

Comment: How would the query look like if we have sort the same on multiple columns

Comment: That would be a different question.